# Python - Reading text files in another folder/directory

Tags: python, string, text, directory

Here is my situation: I've got some .txt files inside a different directory from where I can run the script.

```
mainDir/
    -face/
        -57268-face-_tracker.txt
        -glasses1.txt
        -etc
```

mainDir is where the script should be run. 
All .txt files contain strings like this:

```
face=1  lefteye=closed  righteye=closed
```

My goal is to run all the .txt files in the folder, and for each .txt check if both eyes are closed, if so, add something to the text file, example:

```
face=1  lefteye=closed  righteye=closed  status=sleep
```

So far I can run all the .txt files in the folder, but I cant open them one 
by one.

```
import os


for file in os.listdir("face"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):

    listdir = []
    listdir = file
    print listdir
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

**Edit** 
managed to check every .txt and their strings, but cant compare them

```
import os
face = 'face'
fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
faceDir = os.path.join(fileDir,face)

for file in os.listdir("face"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):

    listdir = []
    listdir = file
    print listdir
    fpath = os.path.join(faceDir, listdir) 
    f = open(fpath)
    print f.readline()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick attempt and has some slightly buggy behaviour (if run repeatedly, it will keep adding status to each relevant line).

Basically, you were most of the way there. Just a case of outputting the result of each loop, in this case by editing the files.

I have used `str.count` to assess which faces are asleep, but there are lots of ways of doing it. You could split the line by `"="` and spaces.

```
import os

fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
faceDir = os.path.join(fileDir, "face")

for file in os.listdir("face"):
    if file.lower().endswith(".txt"):
        fpath = os.path.join(faceDir, file)
        with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
            content = f.readlines()

        for i, line in enumerate(content):
            if line.count("closed") == 2:
                content[i] = line.strip() + "  status=sleep\n"

        with open(fpath, 'w') as f:
            f.write(''.join(content))
```

Comment: works just fine, although it writes the status twice .
Thanks a lot!